# ActionBarSherlock onTouchListener()

Tags: android, android-actionbar, swipe, gesture, ontouchlistener

Is it somehow possible to listen to touch gestures on an ActionbarSherlock?
I would like to recognize swipe gestures on the Actionbar in order to "pull down" a pulldown menu from the top of the display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can detect gestures for a whole `Activity`, where you can implement `onTouchEvent()` callback and use `GestureDetector`.

Detecting touches and gestures only for the action bar is problematic.

AFAIK, the action bar does not expose its views. So there's no api for attaching `OnTouchListener` to native action bar. It won't work there unless you do some hacking into the private parts of the ActionBar. Or you could create a custom view with the `OnTouchListener` in the action bar, then you could detect touches in the area of the custom view. You can set the custom view to take the whole area of the action bar.

Similar situation holds for `ActionBarSherlock` (it is used for all version up to Android 3.2). But the situation here is more favorable, since it is a library you add to your project, you can freely manipulate it any way you want and you can easily access its private parts. `ActionBarSherlock` mimics the native action bar by adding some extra views to the window content. You can access these views and attach `OnTouchListener` to them (you would probably use `R.id.abs__action_bar` or `R.id.abs__action_bar_container`).

Comment: How do you access the views?